# How to combine column values from an array of objects to a single object with string values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, reduce

I have an array that has more than one row (it can vary) as below.

```
const myArray = [{
    name: 'user 100', name2: 'user200', name3: 'user300',
}, {
    name: 'user 101', name2: 'user201', name3: 'user301',
}, {
    name: 'user 102', name2: 'user202', name3: 'user302',
}];
```

I want to combine/merge all these rows in 1 as shown below:

```
{
    name: 'user 100 user 101 user 102',
    name2: 'user200 user 201 user 203',
    name3: 'user300 user 301 user 303',
}
```

Comment: whats you code progress for this output .. post it aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good case for `reduce`, it will loop over every element in your array letting you keep track of attributes across all elements.

`prev` starts out as whatever you gave in the second parameter (in our case it's `{}`)

`next` is an item from your array, starting at the 0th

Use Object.keys to loop over every attribute in your array element, adding them to the originally blank object and passing it along.

`prev` starts empty but after the first loop it holds all properties of element 1, second loop it has element 1 + element 2, etc until it finishes looping.

```js
let myArray = [ {name: 'user 100', name2: 'user200', name3: 'user300'},{name: 'user 101', name2: 'user201', name3: 'user301'}, {name: 'user 102', name2: 'user202', name3: 'user302'} ];

let combined = myArray.reduce((prev, next) => {
  Object.keys(next).forEach(key => {
    prev[key] = (prev[key] ? prev[key] + ' ' : '') + next[key];
  });
  return prev;
}, {})
    
console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries):

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'user 100', name2: 'user200', name3: 'user300',
}, {
  name: 'user 101', name2: 'user201', name3: 'user301',
}, {
  name: 'user 102', name2: 'user202', name3: 'user302',
}];

const result = {};

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => {
    result[key] = `${ (result[key] || '')  } ${ value }`;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

The same can be done using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'user 100', name2: 'user200', name3: 'user300',
}, {
  name: 'user 101', name2: 'user201', name3: 'user301',
}, {
  name: 'user 102', name2: 'user202', name3: 'user302',
}];

const combined = arr.reduce((result, item) => {
  Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => {
    result[key] = `${ (result[key] || '')  } ${ value }`;
  });
  
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(combined);
```